# Why does the voltage divider formula fail in my usage of it in this circuit?

Tags: voltage-divider

[image]

I easily solved this circuit in a different way. The problem is I clearly don't understand something because I think this method should also result in me finding the voltage at point A:
V<sub>AE</sub>=V<sub>A</sub>-V<sub>E</sub> , V<sub>E</sub>=0 so V<sub>AE</sub>=V<sub>A</sub>=
12*k(1/4+1/6)^-1  divided by the total resistance for this path through the circuit k(1.6+3.6+(1/4 +1/6)^-1)

Comment: The voltage at point "E" is ZERO.   It's ground.   Your best bet when given a schematic such as shown above is to REDRAW IT.  This was intentionally drawn to confuse you (and it worked  ;) )

Comment: +1 because good schematic with nodes labeled, and clearly stated question

Comment: @MarkU Well, I think the resistors should be labeled. It's hard to talk about them, forced to use values only since several have the same value.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption that Va is 12V is wrong.

Va is not 12V. You don't know what it is.

You only know that Va-Vd = 12V, and Ve = 0V.

Comment: I meant ve, why cant I use the voltage divider though like I did?

Comment: I think you did not include the resistors of current path A to C because it affects voltage Vc too.

Comment: @ramose - Hi, FYI I have removed (rejected) your attempted edit of this answer, where you tried to ask a clarification question about it. If you need clarification of an answer then (as you have also done) you should add a comment to do that - you should *not* (try to) edit the answer to request that clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @ramose You should learn how it is supposed to be done. Not ask why your method is wrong. It's simpler to explain good practice than it is to delve into how your mind worked (requires first trying to understand it) and doesn't match up with reality (assessment of the mismatch), which is usually a much more complex question to answer. Why not just learn how to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the combination of resistors across the battery, the current is 2mA.

I = 12/(3.6K + (6K ||(1.6K+6K||4K))) = 12V/6K = 2mA

Therefore

Vcd = 2mA * 3.6K = 7.2V

Vac = 12V-7.2V = 4.8V

And now we can use the voltage divider equation:

Vec = 4.8V* 1.6K/(1.6K + 6K||4K) = 4.8V * 1.6K/4K = 1.92V

Vae = 12V - 7.2V -1.92V =  2.88V